# Moving 1 million image files to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, rsync

I run an image sharing website that has over 1 million images (~150GB). I'm currently storing these on a hard drive in my dedicated server, but I'm quickly running out of space, so I'd like to move them to Amazon S3.

I've tried doing an RSYNC and it took RSYNC over a day just to scan and create the list of image files. After another day of transferring, it was only 7% complete and had slowed my server down to a crawl, so I had to cancel.

Is there a better way to do this, such as GZIP them to another local hard drive and then transfer / unzip that single file?

I'm also wondering whether it makes sense to store these files in multiple subdirectories or is it fine to have all million+ files in the same directory?

Comment: This isn't programming related.

Comment: You could just run it at night when your server is not as busy. Also there is the "nice" tool which might reduce your slowness problem.  Since rsync can be configured to skip duplicates, the speed will improve eventually.  I would definitely split the images into subdirectories as many Linux commands start to fail once you get > 100,000 files.  Another issue, you can run out of inodes if you have too many files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Given that the files do not exist (yet) on S3, sending them as an archive file should be quicker than using a synchronization protocol.
2. However, compressing the archive won't help much (if at all) for image files, assuming that the image files are already stored in a compressed format such as JPEG.
3. Transmitting ~150 Gbytes of data is going to consume a lot of network bandwidth for a long time.  This will be the same if you try to use HTTP or FTP instead of RSYNC to do the transfer.  An offline transfer would be better if possible; e.g. sending a hard disc, or a set of tapes or DVDs.
4. Putting a million files into one flat directory is a bad idea from a performance perspective.  while some file systems would cope with this fairly well with `O(logN)` filename lookup times, others do not with `O(N)` filename lookup.  Multiply that by `N` to access all files in a directory.  An additional problem is that utilities that need to access files in order of file names may slow down significantly if they need to sort a million file names.  (This may partly explain why `rsync` took 1 day to do the indexing.)
5. Putting all of your image files in one directory is a bad idea from a management perspective; e.g. for doing backups, archiving stuff, moving stuff around, expanding to multiple discs or file systems, etc.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to split up 1m files into 1,000 sub directories? There's no reason to have more than 1 level of files is there?

Comment: Yes it would.  There are various ways to do this, depending on how they are named and organized, how you want to manage them, etc.

Comment: If I'm going to be splitting up the files, gzip doesn't seem to make sense.. I may just loop through each item in the database, grab the filename, copy the file to S3, change it's filename to it's mysql autoincrement ID. Then I can just split up files based on their ID (plus I'll no longer have to have a filename column in the db). Even if it takes a month, I can at least do some portion each day and start reading from S3 for files that are on S3, and delete the old files on the server to save space. That seem reasonable?

Comment: S3 has no scaling problems with 'folders' - since it has no folders. Each file has a key (that often and usually should look like a path) images/892849845.png

Comment: One nice thing about the S3 file system with keys is that it is an 'infinitely forked' file system. Say you wanted to store all data in S3, including tags for each image, name of image, geo location, etc. Then you can store some thing like images/8248478798.png/tags.json and images/8248478798.png/info.json etc which is really cool.

Answer (score 25):

One option might be to perform the migration in a lazy fashion.

- All new images go to Amazon S3.
- Any requests for images not yet on Amazon trigger a migration of that one image to Amazon S3. (queue it up)

This should fairly quickly get all recent or commonly fetched images moved over to Amazon and will thus reduce the load on your server.  You can then add another task that migrates the others over slowly whenever the server is least busy.

Comment: I took exactly this approach recently, when I needed to migrate 40 million images to S3. I have put the code I used on Github, hopefully someone else finds this useful: https://github.com/mikery/s3cacher

Comment: I favour this idea as well. Elegant.

Answer (score 4):

One option you could use instead of transferring the files over the network is to put them on a harddrive and ship it to amazon's [import/export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) service.  You don't have to worry about saturating your server's network connection etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option, as I don't have easy access to the data center to do something like this.